# Print a selected page using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two pages in a webpage and I want to print out the second page only.

```
page1
........
content
........
.......
end page 1

page 2
.......
content
......
.......
end page 2
```

I am using `window.print()` function it print both two pages but I want to print only second page `page 2`.
One solution is here that I always select second page on window print dialog box.  But I want to do it automatically.
Thanks.

Comment: Hide the first one before you print.

Comment: Two pages inside a web page? Could you explain a little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the content of the first page in a container with a class, `no-print`, and use a print style sheet:

```
@media print {
    .no-print {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

If you need to let the user choose, start out without the class on either page, and then put `no-print` on all of the page(s) that you don't want to print.

```
document.getElementById("id-for-the-page-not-to-print").className += " no-print";
```

Comment: I didn't want to hide the div.

Comment: @Axeem: It only hides it *for printing*, not on screen. That's the whole point of a *print* style sheet (note the `@media print` wrapper).

Comment: In chrome `window.print()` function open chrome print dialog. I want to open window print dialog any suggestion. thanks

Comment: @Axeem: That's a completely unrelated question, but: You have no control over that. All you can do is ask the browser to print. How it does that is up to the browser vendor and any user preferences they provide (for instance, Chrome offers a "Open system print dialog" option at the bottom of its print dialog).